# Android-Status bar Notification

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to now how to create a status notification bar in the home page. Can anyone help me with some codes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
int _icon=R.drawable.icon;

Intent intent = new Intent(_context, your_file.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0, intent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(_icon,_text,when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(_context, _title, _contentText, contentIntent);
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

To cancel notification

```
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: how we can show the percentage dowload in the progress dialog in status bar notification... ?

Comment: @kamal : http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/show-progressbar-in-notification-area-like-google-does-when-downloading-from-android

Comment: But how to add the 55% progress below the progress bar... ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it:
[Android Status Bar](http://javainnovations.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-send-message-to-status-bar-in.html)