# Android: Detecting events on the notification bar

Tags: android, notifications

Is there any way to detect events, like swipe left or right, on the notification bar?

Answer (score 0):

See this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event`

It uses the DeleteIntent.
DeleteIntent: DeleteIntent is a PendingIntent object that can be associated with a notification and gets fired when the notification gets deleted, ether by :

User specific action
User Delete all the notifications.
You can set the Pending Intent to a broadcast Receiver and then perform any action you want.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,                  MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent =     PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
   Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
```

..... code for your notification
       builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
     MyBroadcastReceiver

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends     BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)      {
         .... code to handle cancel
          }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw that, but I am not interested in removal of a notification, or a notification status at any rate, I want to catch the exact swipe events with their directions.

Comment: Why do you want to know which direction it was swiped?

Comment: I want to add an action to the left swipe.