# Check notification has closed in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to check if notification was closed by user?  Is this possible? I mean, if notification is closed by swiping then I would like set a value to DB.

I know how to check if the notification is active but not sure how to get the notification closed by swiping?

How to do it? Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi check this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/14671453/2445061

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the [deleteIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) field of the `Notification` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

**1) Make Method for send Notification**

```
public void sendNotification(String message, int notificationId) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.stack.notificationId", notificationId);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(createOnDismissedIntent(this, 11))
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification note = notificationBuilder.build();
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**2) Make `BroadcastReciver` for detecting swipe `Notification`**

```
public class NotificationDismissedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  int notificationId = intent.getExtras().getInt("com.stack.notificationId");
  /* Your code to handle the event here */
  Log.d("TAG","GET "+notificationId);
}
}
```

**3) Create dismiss intent method**

```
private PendingIntent createOnDismissedIntent(Context context, int notificationId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.stack.notificationId", notificationId);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    return pendingIntent;
}
```

**4) Add `BroadcastReciver` in `manifest`**

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".NotificationDismissedReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
```

**5) call method for Notification**

```
sendNotification("hello world",11);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! How do I check if notification has been clicked or not? Is this possible?

Comment: @SanjanaNair Have you get your answer? I also need help on it.