# Generic Listener when a notification is clicked or dismissed in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to know is there a way for the NotificationListenerService to know if a Notification has been clicked or it has been dismissed. I can see that the Inner class NotificationListenerWrapper in NotificationListenerService has a onNotificationClick() method , but since the NotificationListenerWrapper is hidden with @hide annotation I'm not able to use that.

My question is Can I write a Listener which basically keeps track of whether a notification has been clicked or dismissed.

Basically I want to track if the notifications of my App is being dismissed or they are clicked without any intrusive code in each and every Notification.

P.S. NotificationListenerService provides only onNotificationPosted() and onNotificationRemoved(), but my requirement is to know if notifications are clicked or Removed.

Thanks

Comment: You'll know if your notification was clicked via the pending intent?

Comment: ALL notifications..this is the goal

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with setting content intent?

Answer (score 19):

When you create and show a notification, you provide a `PendingIntent` for when it is clicked (using `.setContentIntent`). You can also define a `PendingIntent` for when it gets dismissed(using `.setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent)`.

If you want to be able to track your Notifications, you need to pass a PendingIntent (like a BroadcastReceiver or IntentService) and pass a few parameters like notificationId and isDismissed and do your work in the BroadcastReceiver.

You can see the complete code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670984/450356) answer.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there is a listener for this. But you can implement this logic in another way using `PendingIntent` and `BroadcastReceiver`

**For OnClick**

add a `ContentIntent` and `BroadcastReceiver`. So you will know that your notification is clicked or not in the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
     Intent onClickIntent = new Intent(this, OnClickBroadcastReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent onClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, onClickIntent, 0);
     mBuilder.setContentIntent(onClickPendingIntent);
```

And inside the `BroadcastReceiver` you can write your logic

```
 public class OnClickBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Open your activity here
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);

        // Do your onClick related logic here
    }

}
```

**For onDismiss**

For this you need to add a `DeleteIntent` into your notification builder

```
 Intent onCancelIntent = new Intent(this, OnCancelBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent onDismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, onCancelIntent, 0);
            mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(onDismissPendingIntent);
```

and `BroadcastReceiver` for this is

```
    public class OnCancelBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Do your logic here
    }

}
```

Don't forget to register these `BroadcastReceiver` to `AndroidManifest`

Comment: Your PendingIntent is using for FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. The question ask for every Notification.

Comment: Does not work anymore, starting from android 12

Comment: It still works, but the broadcast can not launch an activity anymore (so called notification trampolines).