# If user Clears push notification How to handle?

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I am developing android and IOS app, it requires push notification,I have integrated FCM with notification payload,(IOS only supports Notification payload).So as I know in notification payload FCM itself put Notification.Once user clicks then only I can get the data of notification It doent hit onMessage received when the app is killed.If user doesnt click.If he clears how to handle it.Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what do you want to do if user clears the notifications?

Comment: This was answered before. 

Check this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event

Comment: no Actually current scenario is once user clicks I will get some data and based on that i will populate that on UI.If he doesn't click I wont get that data.In case of notification payload.

Comment: To be more simple If we use data payload every push notification data i can get on Onmessage received class.In case of Notification payload I can get data only once user clicks on Notification right.I want that data if user clear the notification also.If you dint get please ask I will explain again.

Answer (score 0):

Open your application while clearing the notification as Facebook and transfer payload to the application. Pending Intent should have your application's one of the activity components like.

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivityName.class);
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Also you can open Services and Broadcasts

Comment: how can i do this any examples please.

Comment: This works with data payload I guess.In case of notification payload I can't use pending intent right?

Comment: You can use the same.

Comment: No If payload is Notification It doesn't comes to on message received.If that is the case How can I do this.

Comment: If you sending notification using the Firebase Console it will not come in onMessageRecived.

Comment: Ya correct because its using notification payload.So in that case How can I get data ex:  { notification: {title: "some message", news_id: news.id, click_action: "NOTIFICATION_DETAILS"}} how to get news_id value if user clears notification.Currently I can get only If user clicks.Problem is if user clears How to get those data.because it wont hit onMessageRecived.with Notification payload and app got kiled it wont come to onMessageRecived.

Comment: If you are only using the data payload, then it should call onMessageReceived(). Unless you're using both notification and data in your payload.

Comment: No I am using only Notification payload.

Comment: Then you can't get your desired result.